# Change JavaFX TabPane background

Tags: background, javafx

I'm developing an application in javaFx and I'm using TabPane to organise content. My problem is that when I put a node as the content of a tab, and then set the background of that same node, the background color gets kind of blurry, as you can see in the image, the background color was defined in a css file.

If anyone knows how to resolve this, would really appreciate the help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3gNH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a victim of this issue:

[JavaFX Image (PNG) transparency crispness being lost when rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160181/javafx-image-png-transparency-crispness-being-lost-when-rendering)

It will likely be fixed in a forthcoming (i.e. Java 8) release.

For now, you may be able to use the work-around documented in the linked question's answer.
To do this, place your image in a CenteredRegion and use that as the first element of a StackPane placed in your tab.  Then layer the rest of the tab content over the image by adding the content to the StackPane.  It's a bit awkward and there may be a more straight-forward solution for your particular case.

```
class CenteredRegion extends Region {
  private Node content;

  CenteredRegion(Node content) {
    this.content = content;
    getChildren().add(content);
  }

  @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
    content.relocate(
      Math.round(getWidth()  / 2 - content.prefWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE)  / 2), 
      Math.round(getHeight() / 2 - content.prefHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE) / 2)
    );
  }

  public Node getContent() {
    return content;
  }
}
```